# Increase touchable target area of a small image?

Tags: windows-phone-7

In a listbox I have a list of titles with an edit icon next to each, how do I increase the touchable area so that even if the user touches part of the title, it actually triggers the image event?

I assume I need to wrap the image in another element but cannot work out what that needs to be.

I tried wrapping the image in a button and add padding to the button but then it pushed the UI elements around, I do not want to affect the presentation, just the none-visible touchable area.

Comment: Just wanted to add that minimal target size is 7mm and optimal is 9mm and more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap it in a button - you're totally in the right ball-park. But you need to edit the control template of the button and reduce down all the standard padding and margin, borders etc. so its just a raw touchable region.

You can then wrap anything in this button and apply your template/style to make anything interactive.

Luke

Comment: +1 I was about to write pretty close to this, then realised it was already written close enough. It sounds like the button was giving you a bit more presentation than you bargained for, but you're on the right path. Just retemplate it to pull out an unecessary styling in the default metro button style.

Comment: @Mick it seems to be one of the most asked about questions!

Comment: yea, usually I've come across people looking to get rid of the padding, when they should be thinking about touch target sizes... good to see people thinking about good touch UI.

Comment: Thanks, on the button I used Height="90" Width="90" BorderThickness="0".
Then inside the button I had my image with height and width set to 48.
I then played around with margin and padding on the button as setting a height and width moves the other UI elements so on the button I used:
Margin="0 -60 0 0" Padding="0 20 0 0"

Answer (score 1):

You could try wrapping in a `Panel` or `Grid`.
Or just adjust the margin and Z-Order.

Answer (score 0):

Put the image in a button, set the size of the button you want & then set the Stroke property to "No brush" on the button to remove the border.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
<Border BorderBrush="Transparent"
        BorderThickness="20,25,20,0"
        Background="Transparent">
        <Grid/>
</Border>
```

or use it in other variations:

```
<Border Background="Transparent">
        <Grid Margin="20 25 20 0"/>
</Border>
```

full sample with button: (no background interaction when pressed at this sample)

```
<Button BorderBrush="Transparent"
        Tag="{Binding SelectedPhoto.commentsCount}">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Border  BorderThickness="20,25,20,0"
                     BorderBrush="Transparent"
                     Background="Transparent">
                <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal"
                             VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <Grid    Margin="0 0 4 0"
                             Visibility="{Binding CommentsAllowedForAlbum,Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Tag}"
                                   Visibility="{Binding SelectedPhoto.HasComments,Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"
                                   Foreground="{StaticResource BlueColorBrush}"
                                   FontSize="{StaticResource MFontSize36}" />
                    </Grid>
                    <Image Source="/Images/photo_comments_icon.png"
                           Stretch="Uniform"
                           MaxWidth="23"
                           Visibility="{Binding CommentsAllowedForAlbum,Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"
                           Margin="0 7 0 0"
                           VerticalAlignment="Top" />

                    <Image Source="/Images/photo_comments_icon_blocked.png"
                           Stretch="Uniform"
                           MaxWidth="23"
                           Visibility="{Binding CommentsAllowedForAlbum,Converter={StaticResource OppositeBoolToVisibilityConverter}}"
                           Margin="0 7 0 0"
                           VerticalAlignment="Top" />

                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```